# Derby 10.10. JNDI connection with JBoss AS 7.1 : Wrong driver class [class org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver]

Tags: jboss, derby

I have created `JNDI connection with JBoss AS 7.1` and able to get DataSource. But when trying to get connection I am getting below error.

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

**Here is exception I have received on eclipse console.**

> 18:21:28,648 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool]
>   (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting
>   to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could
>   not create connection     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:761)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:343)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
>     at
>   com.student.dbtest.DBConnectionTest.doPost(DBConnectionTest.java:53)
>   [classes:]    at
>   com.student.dbtest.DBConnectionTest.doGet(DBConnectionTest.java:36)
>   [classes:]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
>
> Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Wrong driver class [class
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] for this connection URL
>   [jdbc:derby:DerbyDB;create=true]  at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:251)
>     ... 26 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception says, you have the wrong driver class for this connection URL.

Derby supports two types of deployments: embedded, and client/server.

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/getstart/cgsquck70629.html

The two different types of deployment use different JDBC driver class names, and different JDBC Connection URL syntax.

Here's some information about the embedded driver and the embedded URL: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/getstart/twwdactivity1_overview.html

And here's some information about the client driver and the client URL: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/getstart/twwdactivity2.html